# String method is undefined for type string?

Tags: java, string, methods, error-handling

When I try to compile/read Eclipse, I come up with the following error: 
"The method titleCase(String) is undefined for the type String"

Why is that?

Below is code:

```
public class Main {

    String titleCase(String s) {
        String k = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        return k;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String name;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a new name");
            Scanner namescanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            name = namescanner.nextLine();
            String editednames = editednames.titleCase(name);

            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            names.add(editednames);
            System.out.println(names);
        } while (!(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Stop")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this line `String editednames = editednames.titleCase(name);`

Comment: Your method `titleCase` is defined for your class, but not for class `String`. That is what compiler says when you try to run `titleCase` on `editednames` (of type `String`);

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
String editednames = editednames.titleCase(name);
```

with this:

```
String editednames = titleCase(name);
```

Also, you should declare the `titleCase()` method `static` so you can call it from inside the `static main` method:

```
static String titleCase(String s) {
    ...
```

Comment: yeah, and also you should suggest declaring `titleCase` static, otherwise compiler won't allow to call it from `static main`.